# How to remove xml header in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have imported and modified some xml, but when I write out my xml using test.prettify().  It changes the top line of the xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I don't want this change.  How can I just keep the first line unchanged?  What is the easiest way to do this?

If it matters, I'm using the xml parser.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'xml')
```

Comment: Worst case scenario, how can I just manually strip that line out from my xml?

Comment: `re.sub('encoding="utf-8"\?',xml_string_you_want_to_strip)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this using BeautifulSoup's built-ins, but based on your comment, I'll give you the "strip it out" version:

```
xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
print xml_string[:xml_string.find("encoding")-1] + "?>"
```

This is general enough to strip out any encoding from the header (not just utf-8).

Answer (score 0):

You could find the xml and use `replaceWith()` to replace it with the value you want.

Comment: Example? I have been able to replace tags like `<a blabla>` with `replace_with()`, but here the `<?xml blabla>` is giving me grief...