# String replacement: Multiline, Case-Insensitive with Special Characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-re

Objective: Given a string, replace every occurrence of `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'` and uppercase cousins with the empty string `''`.

A `string.replace()` solution and/or a `re.sub()` solution would be great. A solution based on the `BeautifulSoup` module would be considered only as last resort.

1. Attempt based on `string.replace()`:

   ```
   s = '1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
   ## 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ## 2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   h = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
   r = s.replace(h, '')
   ## 1:
   ## 2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   ```

Problem: does not remove occurrences with upper case formatting, as in `UTF-8`.

2. Attempt based on `re.sub()`:

   ```
   import re
   s = '1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
   ## 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ## 2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   h = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
   r = re.sub(h, '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
   ## 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ## 2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   ```

Problem: does not work at all. And yet, a simpler case works:

```
    import re
    s = '1:a\n2:A'
    ## 1:a
    ## 2:A
    h = 'a'
    r = re.sub(h, '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
    ## 1:
    ## 2:
```

I suspect the problem comes from the special characters inside the string, e.g. `<?xml`, but haven't been able to find a solution.

The `<?xml` header is introduced into my code by the `xml` parser via the `BeautifulSoup` module. I haven't had much success with `BeautifulSoup`'s methods here, e.g. `.find_all()` and `.replace_with()`. I tried `soup.decode_contents()`, which worked for some cases but not others. I'm not posting examples of what I tried, because I'd rather not use the module for the particular task at hand (I have a string, I want to output a string, and do not want `BeautifulSoup` to otherwise alter the string). With apologies to the BS die-hards. ;-)

Comment: References (that did not solve my problem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207503/how-do-i-remove-an-xml-declaration-using-beautifulsoup4, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503875/how-to-remove-xml-header-in-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `?` and `.` are regex special characters. You can escape them with, for example `re.escape()`:

```
import re
s = '1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n2:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
h = re.escape('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>') # <-- put re.escape() around the string
r = re.sub(h, '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)               # <-- no need for RE.MULTILINE

print(r)
```

Prints (the `<?xml..?>` string is replaced):

```
1:
2:
```

Comment: Are there situations where `re.MULTILINE` would be needed? No idea what the docs are saying: "When this flag is specified, ^ matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line within the string, immediately following each newline. Similarly, the $ metacharacter matches either at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline)." (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, if you want match beginning/end of lines, you need to use `re.M`. For example: [without `re.M`](https://regex101.com/r/9YD3Zx/1) and [with `re.M`](https://regex101.com/r/9YD3Zx/2) - the example with `re.M` matches all lines, without `re.M` matches only last line.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrej! In 6 minutes I'll be able to upvote your answer. :-)